# Material-UI Slider didn't change active range color

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm making Range Slider component from zero to ten. It should color values that inside the range from the box, but it doesn't.

Here is My Slider Component

```
export function VoteRange({ voteRange, setVoteRange }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setVoteRange(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Slider
        value={voteRange}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        min={0}
        max={10}
        marks={marks}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Handlers from controller

`const [voteRange, setVoteRange] = useState([0, 10]);`

Marks values

```
const marks = [
  {
    value: 0,
    label: '0',
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    label: 5,
  },
  {
    value: 10,
    label: 10,
  },
];
```

I have read the API but didn't find any solution

I expect to see marks in range with active color but when Slider set to 0-10 only '0' and '1' are active. (when Slider set to 0-9 and lower only '0' active)

Comment: This works as I would expect it to using the code you provided: https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-range-0tgj9

Answer (score 0):

updating package @material-ui/lab from 4.0.0-alpha.16 to 4.0.0-alpha.18 fix the problem